# How to log meaningful errors from flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can one log the real errors thrown during execution of futures in dart.

It's not really straight forward how this is done.

Imagine the code below

```
       APIService.fetchUser(userId)
    .then((value))
    .catchError((e)){
        
        /**In Java irrespective of the exception type, I can always get the full message using e.getMessage(); or e.printStackTrace(); but this doesn't work in dart.
Sometimes if I say e.message in my flutter app the app crashes making it very hard for me to know what errors are happening**/
    
        }
```

How can error messages irrespective of exception types always be logged?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the second parameter of `catchError` callback:

```dart
APIService.fetchUser(userId)
  .then((value))
  .catchError((e, s)) {
      print(e);    // Will print the error object
      print(s);    // Will print the stacktrace
}
```